# Badge font too dark on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges

I was using the mobile site earlier and noticed that [when you click on a badge to view info about it](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/badges/47/benefactor), the font turns dark and is really hard to read:

[image]

Comment: BTW, this happens when viewing the mobile site on a desktop computer too - which is how I took the screenshot above...

Comment: I see the same thing in the latest Chrome on both Android and Windows.

Comment: Right - I find it with Safari on Mac and iPhone.

Comment: @BobBroadley Can you provide the URL for the page you were accessing? I'm trying to repro the problem.

Comment: @Hynes http://music.stackexchange.com/help/badges/47/benefactor in mobile view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue. It took a little digging around, but I finally found the culprit: an overriding visited link color that was more specific then the `.badge` and `.badge-tag` code. This has been corrected and will be fixed in the next production build.